# chronyd or ntpd + What are the benefits when using chronyd?

Tags: linux, rhel, time, ntpd

We have Red Hat Linux 7.5 machines and we need to decide between ntpd or chronyd service.

- What are the difference between chronyd to ntpd?
- When is more useful to use chronyd instead of ntpd?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A short answer is: `ntpd` is replaced by `chronyd` as the default NTP daemon in RHEL 7. It is a different implementation which is able to synchronize the system clock faster and with better accuracy.

A long answer is: According Red Hat Solution [2070363](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/2070363)

> *Chrony should be preferred for all systems except for the systems that are managed or monitored by tools that do not support chrony, or the systems that have a hardware reference clock which cannot be used with chrony.*

and the documentation "[Configuring NTP Using the chrony Suite](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system_administrators_guide/ch-configuring_ntp_using_the_chrony_suite)" discusses the "[Differences Between ntpd and chronyd](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system_administrators_guide/ch-configuring_ntp_using_the_chrony_suite#sect-differences_between_ntpd_and_chronyd)".